# Is there a cheat sheet for systemd, for those of us coming from sysvinit systems?

Tags: debian, systemd

I was just a user of GNU/Linux for several years, now I want to learn again at least about troubleshooting.  I could find my way with sysvinit, but systemd has me baffled.  I found quite some documentation for the last several days, but as it seems dauting for me I would like to find a cheat sheet.  I already found two, one for Fedora and a generic one, but I would like something for Debian-like systems, for exemple with Debian commands such as ifup, ifdown &c.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there are several.

Personally I use the Fedora documentation

https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Systemd

There are links on that page for additional resources.

Arch Linux has a nice page also

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/systemd

Comment: Thanks for the links, but it is not quite what I asked.  Given time passed, it seems either there isn’t anything like what I wanted, or that people simply did not care to answer such a stupid question as mine...